# how to write return function correct way without print return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def function(n):

if n % 2 != 0:
    print('weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2, 5):
    print('not weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(6, 20):
    print('weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
    print('not weird')
return n

while True:
    n = int(input('enter the number: '))

    print(function(n))
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter the number: 4
not weird
4
```

Above code, I don't want to print return number 4 again, how to write without representing the return number?

Comment: just use `return None` no need to return anything. or remove print from `print(function(n))`

Comment: Not the question but, use nested tests to avoid checking multiple times `n%2==0` and don't use `x in range(...)` that is inefficient, but rather `x>=low and x<HIGH`.

Answer (score 3):

Change `print(function(n))` to `function(n)`

```
def function(n):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        print('weird')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2, 5):
        print('not weird')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(6, 20):
        print('weird')
    elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
        print('not weird')
    return n
while True:
    n = int(input('enter the number: '))

    function(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

i mean u could just remove the print func at the end like so

```py
def function(n):

if n % 2 != 0:
    print('weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2, 5):
    print('not weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(6, 20):
    print('weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
    print('not weird')
return n

while True:
    n = int(input('enter the number: '))
    function(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just return from the function and not print it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it this way.. remove the return from the function statement and also remove the print when calling this function..
If you only remove the return but still call the function using print(func(n)) then the output would be something like

```
enter the number: 4
not weird
None
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
def function(n):
if n % 2 != 0:
    print('weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2, 5):
    print('not weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(6, 20):
    print('weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
    print('not weird')

while True:
    n = int(input('enter the number: '))
    function(n)
```